# Fetching status code description with jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to fetch status code description I send from asp.net mvc app via jquery and ajax, but can't seem to find where it's hidden.

This is backend:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(403, "someDescription");
```

and this is jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: someUrl,
    method: "POST",
    data: "teamMemberId=" + id,
    statusCode: {
        404: function (obj, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            cancel();
        },
        403: function (obj, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(
                //statusCodeDescription
            );
        },
        200: cancel
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried putting each parameter of the handler function through `console.log` to see what it contains? `textStatus` would be my first thought here.

Comment: I read jquery documentation, and it says status code functions will be treated like success/error ones, so -> error
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )